# Windows phone 8 - bring application to foreground programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am developing an application on windows phone 8 in which - if the application is running in background and an internal event gets fired then application should come to foreground. So, would like to know is there any way to bring application on foreground programmatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way. Only the user can bring an application to the foreground.

What you could do is to create a Toast notification, to notify  the user. That way, if he taps on the notification, the app would open.

[Toast notifications for background agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487170%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

`ShellToast` is one of the features that can be used in applications running in background:

[Features that can be used while running in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)